# JQuery Error in my .PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have some javascript in my html page, that adds 8 div blocks in html.DIV and then ,on click, the blocks hides.

In my local html file(on my pc) it works, but then i've put its code in my php script...

...this block of code shows error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slideDown' of null "

**JavaScript Code:**

```
// JavaScript Document

$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  fillMenu();
});

function fillMenu(){
    fillButton("About", 1, 1);
    fillButton("Www", 2, 2);
    fillButton("PCHelp", 2, 3);
    fillButton("Contacts", 3, 4);
    fillButton("Offices", 3, 5);    
}

function fillButton( btnName, lineIndex, btnIndex) {
    var html = "";
    for(var i = 1; i <=8; i++){
        html += "<div class=\"Line" + lineIndex + "\" id=\"L" + btnIndex +"_" + i +"\"></div>";
    };
    $( "#"+btnName ).prepend(html);

    for(var i = 1; i <=8; i++){
        $("#L" + btnIndex + "_" + i).fadeTo(0,0.6);
    }
}

function hideBtn(btn) {
    var minDX = 100;
    var curr = minDX;
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 1).fadeTo(curr,0);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 2).fadeTo(curr,0);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 3).fadeTo(curr,0);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 4).fadeTo(curr,0);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 5).fadeTo(curr,0);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 6).fadeTo(curr,0);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 7).fadeTo(curr,0);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 8).fadeTo(curr,0);
}

function showBtn(btn) {
    var minDX = 100;
    var curr = minDX;
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 8).fadeTo(curr,0.6);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 7).fadeTo(curr,0.6);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 6).fadeTo(curr,0.6);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 5).fadeTo(curr,0.6);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 4).fadeTo(curr,0.6);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 3).fadeTo(curr,0.6);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 2).fadeTo(curr,0.6);curr=(curr+minDX);
    $("#L" + btn + "_" + 1).fadeTo(curr,0.6);
}

function BtnAbout() {
    $("#ContainerAbout").slideDown( "slow" );
}

function backAbout() {
    $("#ContainerAbout").slideUp( "slow" );
}

function BtnWww() {
    $("#ContainerWww").slideDown( "slow" );
}

function backWww() {
    $("#ContainerWww").slideUp( "slow" );
}

function BtnPCHelp() {
    $("#ContainerPCHelp").slideDown( "slow" );
}

function backPCHelp() {
    $("#ContainerPCHelp").slideUp( "slow" );
}

function BtnContacts() {
    $("#ContainerContacts").slideDown( "slow" );
}

function backContacts() {
    $("#ContainerContacts").slideUp( "slow" );
}

function BtnOffices() {
    $("#ContainerOffices").slideDown( "slow" );
}

function backOffices() {
    $("#ContainerOffices").slideUp( "slow" );
}
```

**My HTML File:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>IT-услуги, частный мастер.</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menuShower.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Border">
<div id="Container">

  <div id="LeftCol">
    <div id="About">
        <div class="MenuLink"">
            <a href="#" target="_self"  onMouseOver="hideBtn(1);" onMouseOut="showBtn(1);" onClick="BtnAbout();">Обо мне</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Www">
        <div class="MenuLink">
            <a href="#" target="_self"  onMouseOver="hideBtn(2);" onMouseOut="showBtn(2);" onClick="BtnWww();">Создание сайтов</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PCHelp">
        <div class="MenuLink">
        <a href="#" target="_self" onMouseOver="hideBtn(3);" onMouseOut="showBtn(3);" onClick="BtnPCHelp();">Консультация</a>    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="RightCol">
    <div id="Contacts">
        <div class="MenuLink">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onMouseOver="hideBtn(4);" onMouseOut="showBtn(4);" onClick="BtnContacts();">Контакты</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Offices">
        <div class="MenuLink">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onMouseOver="hideBtn(5);" onMouseOut="showBtn(5);" onClick="BtnOffices();">Для малого бизнеса</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="ContainerAbout">
    <div id="BackBtnAbout" class="BackButton" onClick="backAbout();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="AboutPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox">
            <b style="font-size:30px;">Обо мне</b></br>
            <p>Здравствуйте! Меня зовут Дмитрий. Я занимаюсь разработкой web-сайтов, а также
            осуществляю и дизайн интерфейсов. У меня уже сложился опыт в данной области и поэтому заказчики остаются довольны результатами моей деятельности. Процесс разработки дизайна довольно творческий, но и надо не забывать, что при этом разработчик сайта должен знать все последнии технологии в данной области. У меня такие навыки есть!<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerWww">
    <div id="BackBtnWww" class="BackButton" onClick="backWww();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="WwwPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Создание сайтов</b></br>
        <p>Я разрабатываю сайты в основном на CMS Joomla последней версии, также возникает ряд задач, которые не поддерживает данная программа. В этом случае есть также выход: договорится с заказчиком о другой программе или писать её самому, но это значительно увеличивает стоимость сайта. Для всех повседневных задач CMS подходит.<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerPCHelp">
    <div id="BackBtnPCHelp" class="BackButton" onClick="backPCHelp();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="PCHelpPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Консультация</b></br>
        <p>Я стараюсь сопровождать клиентов во время всей работы и непрерывно осуществляю с ним связь по e-mail. Для меня важно, чтобы заказчик был проинформирован о каждом шаге работ. Это исключает ряд сложностей при сдаче проекта. Вы можете получить консультацию по оказанию услуг через контакты.<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerContacts">
    <div id="BackBtnContacts" class="BackButton" onClick="backContacts();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="ContactsPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Контакты</b></br>
        <p>Телефон <strong>8 (916) 552-15-15</strong><br/>E-mail <strong>dimasyk@bk.ru</strong> <i>(желательный вид связи)</i><br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerOffices">
    <div id="BackBtnOffices" class="BackButton" onClick="backOffices();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="OfficesPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Для малого бизнеса</b></br>
        <p>Я осуществляю создание не высоконагруженных порталов, т.к. он базируются на CMS. Отсюда не следует, что разрабатываемые сайты являются простыми. Если у вашей фирмы нет сайта, то обращайтесь скорее ко мне!<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="LogoText">Создание сайтов, частный мастер.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**And my php joomla template( looks as same):**

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>IT-услуги, частный мастер.</title>
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/js/menuShower.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Border">
<div id="Container">

  <div id="LeftCol">
    <div id="About">
        <div class="MenuLink"">
            <a href="#" target="_self"  onMouseOver="hideBtn(1);" onMouseOut="showBtn(1);" onClick="BtnAbout();">Обо мне</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Www">
        <div class="MenuLink">
            <a href="#" target="_self"  onMouseOver="hideBtn(2);" onMouseOut="showBtn(2);" onClick="BtnWww();">Создание сайтов</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PCHelp">
        <div class="MenuLink">
        <a href="#" target="_self" onMouseOver="hideBtn(3);" onMouseOut="showBtn(3);" onClick="BtnPCHelp();">Консультация</a>    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="RightCol">
    <div id="Contacts">
        <div class="MenuLink">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onMouseOver="hideBtn(4);" onMouseOut="showBtn(4);" onClick="BtnContacts();">Контакты</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Offices">
        <div class="MenuLink">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onMouseOver="hideBtn(5);" onMouseOut="showBtn(5);" onClick="BtnOffices();">Для малого бизнеса</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="ContainerAbout">
    <div id="BackBtnAbout" class="BackButton" onClick="backAbout();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="AboutPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox">
            <b style="font-size:30px;">Обо мне</b></br>
            <p>Здравствуйте! Меня зовут Дмитрий. Я занимаюсь разработкой web-сайтов, а также
            осуществляю и дизайн интерфейсов. У меня уже сложился опыт в данной области и поэтому заказчики остаются довольны результатами моей деятельности. Процесс разработки дизайна довольно творческий, но и надо не забывать, что при этом разработчик сайта должен знать все последнии технологии в данной области. У меня такие навыки есть!<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerWww">
    <div id="BackBtnWww" class="BackButton" onClick="backWww();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="WwwPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Создание сайтов</b></br>
        <p>Я разрабатываю сайты в основном на CMS Joomla последней версии, также возникает ряд задач, которые не поддерживает данная программа. В этом случае есть также выход: договорится с заказчиком о другой программе или писать её самому, но это значительно увеличивает стоимость сайта. Для всех повседневных задач CMS подходит.<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerPCHelp">
    <div id="BackBtnPCHelp" class="BackButton" onClick="backPCHelp();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="PCHelpPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Консультация</b></br>
        <p>Я стараюсь сопровождать клиентов во время всей работы и непрерывно осуществляю с ним связь по e-mail. Для меня важно, чтобы заказчик был проинформирован о каждом шаге работ. Это исключает ряд сложностей при сдаче проекта. Вы можете получить консультацию по оказанию услуг через контакты.<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerContacts">
    <div id="BackBtnContacts" class="BackButton" onClick="backContacts();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="ContactsPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Контакты</b></br>
        <p>Телефон <strong>8 (916) 552-15-15</strong><br/>E-mail <strong>dimasyk@bk.ru</strong> <i>(желательный вид связи)</i><br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerOffices">
    <div id="BackBtnOffices" class="BackButton" onClick="backOffices();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="OfficesPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Для малого бизнеса</b></br>
        <p>Я осуществляю создание не высоконагруженных порталов, т.к. он базируются на CMS. Отсюда не следует, что разрабатываемые сайты являются простыми. Если у вашей фирмы нет сайта, то обращайтесь скорее ко мне!<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="LogoText">Создание сайтов, частный мастер.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody solve this problem?
**Addition**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByLpYbpPSPSocDJHdFhOOEpOUUU/
^Files of html page and joomla's template.

Comment: `echo $this->baseurl` are missing semicolons.

Comment: it works and without ";", but for test i've add semicolons - and it gives same result.

Comment: how it works without `;`? You mean HTML work, PHP certainly not

Comment: @vlzvl you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon.

Comment: Block '$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  fillMenu();
});' works, but functions 'hideBtn(btn)' don't see a div L_n_n.

Comment: Really? didnt know that, thx :) Still i have the habit of ending my commands

Comment: The error is probably because your `$this->baseurl` is wrong.

Comment: No, this is not, because javascript particulary executed ( function fillMenu(); works).

Comment: If you want you can download files of JS, but you should install joomla and xampp(for example).

Comment: This is not related at all to PHP; it's a Javascript error because at the time `$(...).slideDown()` is called (there are six instances I see), the `$(...)` selector does not return a result. You need to the use the `console` to find the line of code that is causing the error and debug from there.

Comment: Code of JS the same( in .HTML and in Joomla template) but in html page   it dosn't need to debug the code, it should work in PHP page. And errors in calling $(L1_1).fadeTo() function... $(L1_1) was created in fill() function, bun in hideBtn(btn) ($(L1_1).fadeTo()) it has not seen (null object, but in html is created object)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put a block `<jdoc:include type="head" />` after including JQuery

**PHP Page:**

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>IT-услуги, частный мастер.</title>
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8888/joomla/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="Border">
<div id="Container">

  <div id="LeftCol">
    <div id="About">
        <div class="MenuLink"">
            <a href="#" target="_self"  onMouseOver="hideBtn(1);" onMouseOut="showBtn(1);" onClick="BtnAbout();">Обо мне</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Www">
        <div class="MenuLink">
            <a href="#" target="_self"  onMouseOver="hideBtn(2);" onMouseOut="showBtn(2);" onClick="BtnWww();">Создание сайтов</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PCHelp">
        <div class="MenuLink">
        <a href="#" target="_self" onMouseOver="hideBtn(3);" onMouseOut="showBtn(3);" onClick="BtnPCHelp();">Консультация</a>    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="RightCol">
    <div id="Contacts">
        <div class="MenuLink">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onMouseOver="hideBtn(4);" onMouseOut="showBtn(4);" onClick="BtnContacts();">Контакты</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Offices">
        <div class="MenuLink">
            <a href="#" target="_self" onMouseOver="hideBtn(5);" onMouseOut="showBtn(5);" onClick="BtnOffices();">Для малого бизнеса</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="ContainerAbout">
    <div id="BackBtnAbout" class="BackButton" onClick="backAbout();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="AboutPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox">
            <b style="font-size:30px;">Обо мне</b></br>
            <p>Здравствуйте! Меня зовут Дмитрий. Я занимаюсь разработкой web-сайтов, а также
            осуществляю и дизайн интерфейсов. У меня уже сложился опыт в данной области и поэтому заказчики остаются довольны результатами моей деятельности. Процесс разработки дизайна довольно творческий, но и надо не забывать, что при этом разработчик сайта должен знать все последнии технологии в данной области. У меня такие навыки есть!<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerWww">
    <div id="BackBtnWww" class="BackButton" onClick="backWww();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="WwwPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Создание сайтов</b></br>
        <p>Я разрабатываю сайты в основном на CMS Joomla последней версии, также возникает ряд задач, которые не поддерживает данная программа. В этом случае есть также выход: договорится с заказчиком о другой программе или писать её самому, но это значительно увеличивает стоимость сайта. Для всех повседневных задач CMS подходит.<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerPCHelp">
    <div id="BackBtnPCHelp" class="BackButton" onClick="backPCHelp();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="PCHelpPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Консультация</b></br>
        <p>Я стараюсь сопровождать клиентов во время всей работы и непрерывно осуществляю с ним связь по e-mail. Для меня важно, чтобы заказчик был проинформирован о каждом шаге работ. Это исключает ряд сложностей при сдаче проекта. Вы можете получить консультацию по оказанию услуг через контакты.<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerContacts">
    <div id="BackBtnContacts" class="BackButton" onClick="backContacts();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="ContactsPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Контакты</b></br>
        <p>Телефон <strong>8 (916) 552-15-15</strong><br/>E-mail <strong>dimasyk@bk.ru</strong> <i>(желательный вид связи)</i><br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContainerOffices">
    <div id="BackBtnOffices" class="BackButton" onClick="backOffices();"> Назад
    </div>
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <div id="OfficesPhoto" class="Photo"></div>
        <div class="TextBox"><b style="font-size:30px;">Для малого бизнеса</b></br>
        <p>Я осуществляю создание не высоконагруженных порталов, т.к. он базируются на CMS. Отсюда не следует, что разрабатываемые сайты являются простыми. Если у вашей фирмы нет сайта, то обращайтесь скорее ко мне!<br/><a href="#" target="_self" >Подробнее...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="LogoText">Создание сайтов, частный мастер.</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8888/joomla/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/js/menuShower.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing semi-colons.

```
<title>IT-услуги, частный мастер.</title>
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/myjobsitetitletemplate/js/menuShower.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: it works and without ";", but for test i've add semicolons - and it gives same result. Block '$( document ).ready(function() { // Handler for .ready() called. fillMenu(); });' works, but functions 'hideBtn(btn)' don't see a div L_n_n.

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs when your javascript is loaded before the elements are rendered.Make sure your javascript is placed right before the closing body tag.

```
 <body>
    ...
    <!-- Your Js --->
 </body>
```

Comment: I checked this option - does not work ... I've used $(document).ready() function. but in **local html code file works without errors** .

Comment: @hardcoder1 In your joomla template,try calling the script (like how it is in the HTML) ,without using php,because it worked fine when I tested it in my server.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your jquery code is conflicting with something. Try this using

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Your code will be like below-

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();


$j("#ContainerOffices").slideDown( "slow" );
```